# Is it considered grey/black hat SEO if I modify the sizing of the headings?

Tags: html, css, seo

The situation is the following:

The page's title is H3, the article's title is H2 and some keyword/important sentence is H1 in the article. They have custom css classes on them, so the H3 looks like a H1, and the H1 looks like normal text. Is this considered grey/black hat SEO, or Google doesn't care about their rendered size?

Comment: Read the [tag:seo] tag wiki.  Also, [what is on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS far as I know Google is not interested in how it looks like. But the heading structure is more important.

So the H1 is the most important tag with your relevant SEO text. After that the H2 tag with related information to the H1 tag etc.

An good article you can read is this page:
https://yoast.com/headings-use/

And ofcours Google own Userguide is an must read:
http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Good luck!